# open file on server with notepad via windows cmd in python

Tags: python, cmd, server

I am trying to opne a file that is located on a server using the windows cmd. What I do is basically the following thing:

```
import os 
os.system('pushd '+ \\Server\PathToFile)
os.system('start Notepad '+ NameOfFile)
```

The point is that this works if I enter it by hand in the cmd. If I try to do it within python it does not work. I get this error message:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the path given above as current directory.
UNC-paths are not supported, therefore the windows-directory is used as 
current directory.
```

The actual error message is in german, that's why I translated it and I'm not sure whether it's understandable or not. What actually happens is that the path where notepad is looking for the current file is  C:\Windows instead of the path that I indicated.

Answer (score 4):

Windows doesn't support setting the current directory to an UNC path, and it wouldn't have worked anyway since those are 2 separate `os.system` commands.

You could mount a drive on this path and use `os.chdir`, but that would make it more complex yet!

You don't really need current directory change. Moreover `os.system` is deprecated, it's recommended to use `subprocess` instead.

So change your code to run the command providing full path to the file:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["start","notepad",os.path.join("\\Server\PathToFile",NameOfFile)],shell=True)
```

but I suspect you'd be better off with

```
os.startfile(os.path.join("\\Server\PathToFile",NameOfFile))
```

(default associations of Windows will probably open "notepad" in background, that's one-line & simple, & users can even change the editor used by just changing text file association in windows)